# How to save a plotted vector to a matrix?

Tags: matlab, ginput

I want to write a code that plots columns in a matrix one by one. while plotting, the code should allow few seconds to look at each column plotted before moving to the other one.

During those few seconds the user should have the ability to save the plotted vector to a new matrix by clicking on the figure.

```
x=[1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9]%for matrix creation

%hold on%this function for multiple plots

for i=1:3

  plot(x(:,i))

  pause(2)

end

hold off

for i=1:3

  [x]=ginput(i)%this function for print the ploted vector

end
```

The problem with my code is:

1- I could not implement the clicking after every vector

2- clicking with ginput gives 1 point and the whole plotted vector

(any help for either problems is appreciated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by an if statement instead.

```
sample = data(150:220,:);
new =[];
for i=1:size(data,2)

    plot(sample(:,i))

    [x,y]=ginput(1);%this function for print the ploted vector
    if y < 0 
        disp('small')
    else
        new = [new,sample(:,i)];
     end
end
```